# web3 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'methods' of undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am made a coin flip dapp and am using ganache to deploy it. A player has to selects a number between 0 and 1. I read this error means "the contract is undefined" but I do not know how to solve this error. [My github repo](https://github.com/oneworldcoder/Coinflip-Part1)

My main.js code is

```
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider);
var contractInstance;
var contractAddress = "0x2Ae24960e9f6331e68Ef6c19b7FA15094adFdA98";
var number;
var guess;

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.ethereum.enable().then(function(accounts) {
      contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {from: accounts[0]});
      console.log(contractInstance);
    });
    $("#bet_0").click(bet(0));
    $("#bet_1").click(bet(1));
});

function bet(number) {
  contractInstance.methods.flipCoin(number).send({value: web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether")})
  .on("transactionHash", function(hash) {
    console.log(hash);
  })
  .on("confirmation", function(confirmationNr) {
    console.log(confirmationNr);
  })
  .on("receipt", function(receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
  })
  .then(function() {
    fetchAndDisplay(guess);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);

  })

}

async function fetchAndDisplay(guess) {
  await contractInstance.methods.outcome.call().call().then(function(res) {
    if(guess=res){
      console.log("Result is " + res + " you won!");
      $("#outcome_display").text("You Won!");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Result is " + res + " you lost!");
      $("#outcome_display").text("You Lost!");
    }

  })

}
```

Comment: Where is your `abi` defined ?

Comment: It's in the same folder as index.html. I also tried using ```window.abi``` In the console I can see the contract instance.

Comment: I solved the above error by changing the code block                        
`$("#bet_0").click( () =>{
      bet(0)
    });
    $("#bet_1").click( () => {
      bet(1)
    });` But I have a new Metamask error

Comment: `ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.` I checked the require statements but I could not find any errors.

Comment: You can open a new question for your issue with the smart contract execution.